# How to select Max. switching voltage and current of Relay for a LC resonant circuit

Tags: relay

[image]

I have a LC resonant circuit as the above shows. And I want to switch the inductor between L1 and L2 with relays (sometimes L1 is used and sometimes L2 is used). The high voltage point between the inductor and capacitor has a voltage about 400Vp-p, and the current in the inductor is about 10Ap-p. Could I think a relay with max. switching voltage no less than 200VDC and max. switching current no less than 5A is needed? Or how should I select a relay for this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stick with solid state - add another couple of MOSFETs to your bridge and select one of the left pairs for driving the appropriate inductor: -

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea. By the way, you mean a solid state relay is used to switch the control voltage between the Gates of different MOSFETs pairs?

Comment: No, "solid-state" just means avoidance of mechanical parts that normal relays have. Just normal logic routing to option A inputs or option B inputs with "solid-state (i.e. silicon ICs)" will do the trick. "solid state" doesn't mean "solid-state relay".